# Odata source missing from ssis toolbox

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, odata, sql-server-2014

I've followed the install instructions for the 32 bit SQL Server 2014 feature pack, but can't seem to see the odata source component in the ssis toolbox. I've tried installing the 64 bit feature pack and still have the same problem even after refreshing the toolbox. I copied the Odata dll's in the DTS/ConnectionManager and DTS/PipelineComponents folders to make sure they are both in folders within ProgramFiles (x86) and ProgramFiles as specified here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403356(v=sql.120).aspx

Infrastructure installed SQL across C: and D:

Now I can see the component in visual studio 2013 shell, but still not in visual studio 2012. Any ideas please?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

> Now I can see the component in visual studio 2013 shell, but still not in visual studio 2012

- Visual Studio 2013 = SQL Server 2014 SSIS packages
- Visual Studio 2012 = SQL Server 2012 SSIS packages

A 2014 package is not compatible with 2012 and neither are the components. If you're building for 2012, you need to get the installation that pushes the DLLs into the 110 folder. If you're building for 2014, you'll need the assemblies that reside in 120.

And whichever/both you install, they'll all need to be registered in the global assembly cache during their installation on your development **and** the server. Many people skip installing on the server and then wonder why their packages do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Re-download the .msi for the oData source for SSIS.  It does the proper installs for you.  I figured since this question is almost 3 years old it needed an updated answer.  I'm using VS 2015 shell with SSDT and SQL Server 2014 with SSIS....it worked for me...kind of.   There are other issues I'm having, but those are for another discussion.